# Email address book stolen

Tags: privacy

The way I have set up my email system allows me to put the name of a company (that say I am buying a book from) in front of the @ and my domain name.net after it.  So, when I get an email from amazon@********.net, and it's from a different company, I would know that Amazon have sold my email address or their email address book has been stolen.

This has happened today with groupon.co.uk who tell me that it's not their fault that I have received a nasty spam email addressed to groupon@********.net, it's probably come from a cookie which I have on my computer.  Is that possible?

Comment: Please define "nasty spam". Advert? Phishing? Scam?

Comment: The email tried to get me to download a file ending .arj

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. If you've only used the groupon@****.net email address on the Groupon website then any cookie it might be in is only readable by Groupon themselves, or by a third-party whose content Groupon have permitted to appear on their website (unless the security of your own computer has been compromised).

Comment: Don't you contradict your own answer? The likely scenario is that it IS from a Groupon cookie, and that the sender is, or got the cookie from a 3rd party.

Comment: If it's a third party authorised by Groupon, then that's still their responsibility. It can't be a third party doing it without Groupon's cooperation.